# How to echo (or print) to the js console with php

Tags: php

In javascript, I can print to the debug console using

```
console.log("Message here");
```

I'm now writing a php script, and would like to print to the debug console. Using the above code doesn't work in php. It seems I need to use either echo or some other command but I need the output to appear inside the output console, not the browser window.

Comment: I don't know of a way to echo to the console but you certainly can write to an error log which would be best. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: not possible. php runs on the server and cannot "talk" to your browser's JS debug console. at best PHP could do something like `echo "<script>console.log('hello, world');</script>"`, but that's not php "logging", that's php outputting JS code that triggers the logging.

Comment: can you give example for what you want to print there?

Comment: PHP lives on the server side and logging is usually done using log files on the server. The browser console is for client side code (i.e. JavaScript). If you really want to debug some PHP app, you should probably get in touch with [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof)

Comment: @Squeegy: Thanks for pointing out that I should be using php's error log for this instead of outputting to the console.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
<?php
   echo '<script>console.log("Your stuff here")</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Works! But in my case I need to echo a variable, so the code looks like this: `echo "'<script>console.log(\"$value\")</script>'";`

Comment: How about array data?

Comment: `echo '<script>console.log('.$variable.')</script>';` is the best way to print out variables I think.

Comment: @blackandorangecat  `echo '<script>console.log('.json_encode($variable).')</script>';`

Comment: @RobbiNespu  json_encode() the var..  if you want to use `console.table(),`, you'll need to jump quite a few hoops... or use a library such as https://github.com/bkdotcom/PHPDebugConsole

Answer (score 18):

This will work with either an array, an object or a variable and also escapes the special characters that may break your JS :

```
function debugToConsole($msg) { 
        echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($msg).")</script>";
}
```

**Edit :** Added `json_encode` to the `echo` statement. This will prevent your script from breaking if there are quotes in your `$msg` variable.

Comment: Re: comments to accepted answer, wrapping `$VAR` with `json_encode($VAR)` was necessary for preventing quotes within the variable from breaking the dump to `console.log()`. E.g.: `echo '<script>console.log('.json_encode($charge).')</script>';`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  echo "<script>console.log({$yourVariable})</script>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way:

```
<?php
   echo "<script>console.log('$variableName')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: But then `$variableName` cannot contain quotes... you must escape them first. check other answers

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon   escape via `json_encode()`... will support, strings, arrays, bool, null....

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways to print variable's value in PHP. One of them is to use buildin var_dump() function. If you want to use var_dump(), I would also suggest to install Xdebug (from https://xdebug.org) since it generates much more readable printouts.

The idea of printing values to browser console is somewhat bizarre, but if you really want to use it, there is very useful Google Chrome extension, PHP Console, which should satisfy all your needs. You can find it at [consle.com](http://consle.com/) It works well also in Vivaldi and in Opera (though you will need "Download Chrome Extension" extension to install it). The extension is accompanied by PHP library you use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bkdotcom/PHPDebugConsole

Support for all the javascript console methods:
assert, clear, count, error, group, groupCollapsed, groupEnd, info, log, table, trace, time, timeEnd, warn
plus a few more:
alert, groupSummary, groupUncollapse, timeGet

```
$debug = new \bdk\Debug(array(
    'collect' => true,
    'output' => true,
    'outputAs' => 'script',
));

$debug->log('hello world');
$debug->info('all of the javascript console methods are supported');
\bdk\Debug::_log('can use static methods');
$debug->trace();
$list = array(
    array('userId'=>1, 'name'=>'Bob', 'sex'=>'M', 'naughty'=>false),
    array('userId'=>10, 'naughty'=>true, 'name'=>'Sally', 'extracol' => 'yes', 'sex'=>'F'),
    array('userId'=>2, 'name'=>'Fred', 'sex'=>'M', 'naughty'=>false),
);
$debug->table('people', $list);
```

this will output the appropriate `<script>` tag upon script shutdown

alternatively, you can output as html, chromeLogger, FirePHP, file, plaintext, websockets, etc

upcomming release includes a psr-3 (logger) implementation

Answer (score 0):

For something simple that work for arrays , strings , and objects I builed this function:

```
function console_testing($var){

    $var = json_encode($var,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    $output = <<<EOT
    <script>
        console.log($var); 
    </script>
EOT;

    echo $output;

}
```